# Using imported variable in Celery task

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a Flask app which uses SocketIO to communicate with users currently online.  I keep track of them by mapping the user ID with a session ID, which I can then use to communicate with them:

```
online_users = {'uid...':'sessionid...'}
```

I delcare this in my `run.py` file where the app is launched, and then I import it when I need it as such:

```
from app import online_users
```

I'm using Celery with RabbitMQ for task deployment, and I need to use this dict from within the tasks. So I import it as above, but when I use it it is empty even when I know it is populated.  I realize after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350471/celery-doesnt-work-with-global-variable) that it is because each task is asynchronous and starts a new process with an empty dict, and so my best bet is to use some sort of database or cache.

I'd rather not run an additional service, and I only need to read from the dict (I won't be writing to it from the tasks).  Is a cache/database my only option here?

Comment: The celery task running in a different process, it can't access the dict after it has been started. A cache in Redis or the like is probably your best option.

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow have the main app process listen for requests sent out by a task process to call a function back in the main process?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. You can implement a Redis pubsub to send/receive messages between the two processes.

Comment: It appears the author of flask-socketio has recently [implemented](http://python-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#using-a-message-queue) exactly this in the package using kombu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [this discussion](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/47) which seems to be a solution for exactly what I'm trying to do.

> Communication through a message queue is now implemented in package python-socketio, through the use of Kombu, which provides a common API to work with several message queues including Redis and RabbitMQ.

Supposedly an official release will be out soon, but as of now it can be done using an [additional package](http://python-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#using-a-message-queue).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you have in the dict.... If it's something you can serialize to string you can serialize it to Json and pass it as an argument to that task. If it's an object you cannot serialize, then yes you need to use a cache/database.

Comment: It is serializable, however it needs to be read in real time and these tasks are queued with a countdown so the data would be stale by the time they executed.  I guess I'll just go the cache route and use Redit for this.

Comment: If that is the case, then yeah. You have to use a cache of some sort.