# global list on Celery with Django

Tags: python, django, process, celery

I'm using Celery and have there a global list since I cannot use global variable in Django. 
I add items to that list on demand.

The problem is that when I try to get the global list from Celery, sometimes I don't get the updated list. 
For example, I might get empty list when I know I already inserted items to it.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350471/celery-doesnt-work-with-global-variable) that Celery run with multiple process so I edited the running command of Celery to - `celery -A tasks worker -c1`and now I should have only one process but still for some reason I have the same problem.

**Note**: when I fail to get the right list and I refresh the page few time I do get the updated list.

I think maybe Celery is still run few process instead of one or running few threads but it really shouldn't since I use the flag `-c1`

**EDIT:** I think that maybe few workers are running simultaneously. I tried to kill them but each time I kill one, a new one is born somehow.

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.task import periodic_task

import time
import threading

global_list = [[],[],[],[],[]]
global_list_protection = [[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]]]

@shared_task
def add(log_array, is_protection):

    i = 0
    if (is_protection == "true"):
        global global_list_protection

        while (i<len(global_list_protection) and global_list_protection[i]!= [[],[],[]]):
            i = i+1
        if (i<len(global_list_protection)):
            global_list_protection[i] = log_array
            return i
        return -1

    if (is_protection == "false"):
        global global_list

        while (i<len(global_list) and global_list[i]!= []):
        i = i+1

        if (i<len(global_list)):
            global_list[i] = log_array
            return i
        return -1
    return -1

@shared_task
def get(is_protection, index):


    if (is_protection == "true"):
        global global_list_protection
        return global_list_protection[int(index)]

    if (is_protection == "false"):
        global global_list
        return global_list[int(index)]
    return None
```

**views.py**

```
def send_to_celery(log_array, is_protection):
    from polls.tasks import add

    index_save = add(log_array, is_protection)
    return index_save


def get_from_celery(is_protection, index):
    from polls.tasks import get 

    log_array = get(is_protection, index)
    return log_array
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saving a global list with celery? Celery is a Distributed Task Queue that is in my eyes not directly related to any "saving". Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: @Tim I didn't explain myself correctly. I don't have any global list, I just use global list

Comment: Could you provide some example code from your view and your celery task to show how you retrieve the global variable?

Comment: @Tim I added now. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not using Celery in your code example. Celery tasks can be called directly like any other function. Only if you use the special celery methods like `delay()`, the tasks are send asynchronously to celery. In your example, your code is executed in the server threads and therefore depend on the thread that is calling the function.

Even though I have never done this, you would probably need to send the task to celery and then wait for the result to be returned. The following code could work, though I did not test it:

**views.py**

```
def send_to_celery(log_array, is_protection):
    from polls.tasks import add

    async_result = add.delay(log_array, is_protection)
    index_save = async_result.get()
    return index_save

def get_from_celery(is_protection, index):
    from polls.tasks import get 

    async_result = get.delay(is_protection, index)
    log_array = async_result.get()
    return log_array
```

Comment: I appreciate you help but it's not working for me. I get stack in the get() although I see in the console that the task succeeded.

Comment: Is your result backend setup properly so that the results can be propagated back to your view? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results

Comment: I added backend and it takes too on for my amount of data. I guess Celery was not meant for my purpose.

Comment: yes, that could be. Sending a task asynchronously and waiting for the reply does take a considerable amount of time. Did you consider saving your global information in a database or a key-value store like Redis?

Comment: Yes but it's a great amount of temporal data so it doesn't feel right

Comment: How about memcached?

Comment: Now I'm trying Django cache with using memcached. Hope it will work