# global variable in a task

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery director to write celery task. And I need to pass parameter from one step to downstream step. So I write the following decorator to do that. But the decorator need to access a parameter named params defined in the task, so I used a global variable (global params). The question is: will the global variable result in case condition? Suppose the first execution set params to {"test":{"v1":1}}, and the second execution set params to {"test":{"v1":2}} because they pass different kwargs. If they are running at nearly t he same time, is it for both execution see the same params value since they are global?

```
def inject_params(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        inherit_params = {}
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, dict):
                if "params" in arg:
                    inherit_params = arg["params"] |inherit_params
        new_kwargs = inherit_params|kwargs
        result = func(*args, **new_kwargs)
        global params
        return {"params": params|inherit_params, "result": result}
        return result
    inner.__name__ = func.__name__
    return inner

params={}


@task(name="EVALUATE_DELETE_PERFORMANCE")
@inject_params
def evaluate_delete_performance(*args, **kwargs):
   
    global params
    params = {"test":kwargs}
   
    return "some value"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Global variable(`params`) will contain inconsistent data

Why? Let's imagine that we have *X* workers. Scheduler started first task on first worker. A worker doesn't stop processing at the moment of writing / reading global variables. You can easily check this with a regular counter(just an example):

`tasks.py`:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost')

COUNTER = 0

@app.task
def plus_one(name: str):
    global COUNTER
    COUNTER += 1
    print(f'name: {name}. counter: {COUNTER}')
```

`run_task.py`:

```
from tasks import plus_one

for i in range(1000):
    plus_one.delay('first')
    plus_one.delay('second')
```

- run celery from first terminal ( `celery -A tasks worker` )
- run tasks from second terminal ( `python run_task.py` )

You'll see a different counter value. Global variables do not solve race condition or concurrency problems. In general, I think that it is better to use them only for constants / static flags / etc.

By the way, [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350471/celery-doesnt-work-with-global-variable)